# New to matlab, Audio

Tags: matlab, audio

I'm new to matlab and i really need help with a problem. My problem is that when I used the code the sound played is very different from the sound recorded on the file. this is the code
for selection button

```
handles = guidata(hObject); 
[y,Fs,nbits]=wavread('renovation 4th floor.WAV');
noise=y;
handles.noise1=noise;
n=1;
handles.number=n;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

play button

```
n=handles.number;
switch n
case 1
sound(handles.noise1)
case 2
sound(handles.noise2)
case 3
sound(handles.noise3)
case 4
sound(handles.noise4)
end
```

Comment: how about using `sound(y,Fs,nBits)`?

Comment: I'll add something to thewaywewalk comment. If you don't specify a value for Fs in your sound call (Fs is the sample rate of the signal btw), you'll end up with the default value (8192 Hz), which is pretty high! That's why you might be hearing a fast, high pitched sound instead of your sample

Comment: ahhhh i tried it and it does work, thanks for the answer